# Having trouble with codeigniter check box on remember me button

Tags: codeigniter, cookies

I am storing the username and password in cookie but i have little trouble with remember me button i want that when user check the check box the cookie store the values else only log in the user but the problem is here when i put the check in my controller it wont work i know the problem is in my if condition please some one sort me out the problem or correct my syntax will be really thankful. Here is my code of controller and view.

```
 function verifying(){
   $data=array(
            'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
            'password'=>$this->input->post('password')
            );
        if($this->input->post('remember_me')=="checked")
        {
                 $cookie = array(
                    'name'   => 'username',
                    'value'  => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'expire' =>  86500,
                    'secure' => false
                );

                $cookie1 = array(
                    'name'   => 'password',
                    'value'  => $this->input->post('password'),
                    'expire' =>  86500,
                    'secure' => false
                );
        }
                $this->input->set_cookie($cookie); 
                $this->input->set_cookie($cookie1);

       $result=$this->user->verify("signup",$data);
       if($result)
       {
           $sess_arrau=array();
           foreach($result as $row)
           {
               $sess_arrau=array('username'=>$row->username);
           }
            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_arrau);
            $data['username']=$this->session->userdata('username');
            $this->load->view("success",$data);   
       }

       //$this->load->view("success",$sess_array);

   else{
  redirect("signin");
   }
   }
```

Log in page code.

```
<?php
 $username=$this->input->cookie('username', false);
  $password=$this->input->cookie('password',false);
 if($this->session->userdata('username')!=''){
 redirect("index/post");
 }
 echo form_open("index/verifying");
 echo form_input('username',"$username",'placeholder="username"');

 echo form_checkbox('remember_me','REMEMBER ME',FALSE);
 echo form_label('REMEMBER ME','remember_me');
  ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<?php
 echo form_password('password',"$password",'placeholder="password"'); 
 echo form_submit('submit','Signin');
 echo form_close();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that "checked" won't be the value of the input when it has been checked.  Instead the value will be "REMEMBER ME" because this is the second parameter you have passed to the `form_checkbox` function.

So in your controller rather than do

```
if($this->input->post('remember_me')=="checked")
{
    //Do stuff here...
}
```

You need to do

```
if($this->input->post('remember_me')=="REMEMBER ME")
{
    //Do stuff here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot working fine with both answers before your answer i user the approach which in 2nd answer but any how you was the first so i will accept your answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

quite easy the answer above is correct too and the other short approach is like that.

```
if($this->input->post('remember_me')!="")
```

And it will work fine too.